# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Object>'

Tags: android, flutter

I got the the following  error for below code. I was attempting to navigate to the next page. I was able to navigate just once and then I got the error mentioned above. Please do help me on this. I tried even using await but await is not supported for  builder: (BuildContext context) => SubmitArticles()).

```
class UserSubmitOption extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserSubmitOptionState createState() => _UserSubmitOptionState();
}

class _UserSubmitOptionState extends State<UserSubmitOption> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext dynamic) => MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:SafeArea (
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[800],
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            appBar: AppBar(
                toolbarHeight: 60,
                backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                title: Text("What do you want to submit?",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold)),
                centerTitle: true,
                leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,color:Colors.black,size:25,),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserMenu())))),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Wrap(spacing: 50, runSpacing: 50.0, children: <Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              SubmitQuiz();
                              setState(() {

                              });
                            },
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              child: Card(
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                borderOnForeground:true,
                                shadowColor: Colors.white,
                                elevation: 20.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.vpn_key_outlined,size:60,color:Colors.black,
                                          ), //     Image.asset("assets/todo.png",width: 64.0,),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 7.0,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Quiz",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 17.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5.0,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ),
                            )),
                        GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute (
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SubmitArticles())
                            );},
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              child: Card(

                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                elevation: 20.0,
                                shadowColor:Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon (
                                            Icons.article_outlined,size:60,
                                          ),
                                          //    Image.asset("assets/note.png",width: 64.0,),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 7.0,
                                          ),

                                          Text(
                                            "Articles",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 17.0),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5.0,
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ),
                            )),
                                           ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )));
}
```

Comment: We need more code. I think that your method SubmitArticles returns a Future and no Route. If it returns a route, you have to add await before the call: await SubmitArticles()

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access route in the wrong way
use instead:

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
builder : (context) => SubmitArticles())
);
```

i hope it work with you.
happy coding!

Comment: And above line is causing error on                                  return MaterialApp(  of  following code                                                                                       
     void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      home: AuthService().handleAuth(),
    );
  }

}

Comment: This is the error                                                              
                The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'